# Is the hadran a shevua?

Tags: torah-study, nedarim-shevuot, siyum

When you say the hadran after finishing a mesechta are you making a promise to do so? Should you omit the hadran if you have no plans of ever returning to study that gemara again?

Comment: If anything it's a shevua, not a neder. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14884/759

Comment: Hello bchol beisi neeman and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for your interesting question. It would be more informative to those who might answer and more descriptive to those who might read it if you excerpt or refer to the exact text that gives rise to the question. While you are here, consider registering your account to gain all of the abilities of a Mi Yodeya User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doubtful, it is exceedingly likely that the average person does not plan to return and finish the same mesechta within 3 regalim (pok chazi). Therefore this cannot be a common form of a shevua.

Comment: Perhaps that points to evidence that it isn't, but it doesn't provide a halachic reason for it not to be, which is what askers on this site are generally looking for. -1 That's besides the fact that your answer is based on the assumption that if Hadran Alakh was a shevua, it would be binding for three regalim, for which you provide no halachic evidence.

Comment: What kind of signature is 00?  isn't this the same signature that you, Vram, tried to use before and people objected to it? So, are you now posting and commenting on your own posts as if you're two different people?

Comment: (Hamevin Yavin) Soooo confused about who is answering and commenting above!!!  --->

Comment: not sure what is so confusing. the former vram account has been renamed to ه ه. this is a new vram account totally unaffiliated with the other account.