# Machsor Tom. I - Prayer book?

Tags: jewish-books, prayer-book, publications

I found a very old book written in the Hebrew language. At the bottom of the title page it is written " Machsor Tom. I". It was printed in Austria by Jos. Schlesinger Librairie.
I searched on line but could not find any reference to Machsor Tom. I; I have found II and VII. I presume it is a prayer book for special occasions. Does anyone know for what festival it is/was used?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Is there a table of contents?  (Hebrew's fine.)  If so, if you could scan that and the title page and add them to your post, it might help us identify which holy day this is for.

Comment: I have got first three volumes of Machsor. I will be interested to get all volumes. Let me know if you ever willing to sell the volume VII. Thanks.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46051

Answer (score 6):

As Noach has pointed out, Tom. stands for Latin "tomus", volume, thus you have volume one of a mahzor, or holiday prayer book. The Schlesingers were a well-known Austro-Hungarian family whose printing firm specialized in printing prayerbooks (see [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=-wUg6rlWS2kC&pg=PA178&dq=%22Joseph%20Schlesinger) and [here](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0016_0_16101.html)). If you can post a scan of the title page we will be able to tell you more about it and what it was for.

Comment: I suspect from the OP that we are dealing with a book of piyutim (liturgical poetry) for special shabbatot, such as the four parshiot, shabbat Breishit, et c..

Answer (score -4):

There are 7 Feasts of Israel. This book contains the Ancient Hebrew for Ashkenazim relating to those occasions. It is called a Siddur, a Hebrew prayer book. If you have 3 of them, there are four missing.

Comment: I've edited your answer to make it less conversational and more appropriate for this site. This is not your personal email exchange ([no offense](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15030/no-offense-loophole)]). But welcome to Mi Yodeya. Can you provide more information relevant to the question? What does Ashkenazim have to do with it, and what does the numbering mean?