# Why does the Machzor Rabba sometimes have an א at the bottom of the page?

Tags: prayer-book, aleph-bet-letters, nusach-ashkenaz, high-holidays

My Machzor Rabba, nusach Ashkenaz, sometimes prints a dot, and sometimes an א at the bottom of the page. Anyone know why?

I've included pictures of a double page with two dots, one with two alephs, and one with one of each.

[image: two dots]
[image: two alephs]
[image: one and one]

Comment: Could be its stands for נוסח אשכנז?

Comment: More useful would be to include publication info. Who printed this text? What edition is it?

Comment: @DoubleAA printed by Shai Lamora. I can't find anything that says what edition/year it is.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37191

Comment: Scimonster, you daven Ashkenaz in Israel?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Yes, why?

Comment: Of the many folks I know who live in Israel, only some of the chareidim use Ashkenaz. My Religious Zionist-type cousins all use Sefard.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Well, we only have a nusach Sefard shul, but there is an Ashkenaz underground. :) (Dati-Tzioni)

Comment: You know any Ashkenaz minyanim in Jlem?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt There's the Gra minyan factory in Shaarei Chesed. I've davened there during the week when i'm in J'lem. But, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - http://www.godaven.com/list.asp?fpdbr_0_pMv=First&Name=jerusalem&Nusach=Ashkenaz yields 62 results - probably 10% of the total of those that exist. I even know of 3 that would qualify as Yekkish.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, thanks for that, although I was in E"Y in Elul, so it's a bit late. FWIW, I davened at the Italian Synagogue (nusach Bene Romì, or Italki) the first Shabbat and with a family minyan the second. Unfortunately, due to factors related to R' Kook זצ”ל, that minyan was nusach Sephard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You find this a lot in older Sefarim. Usually you can find these in the margin closest to the binding - often hidden in the binding.

It seems that this was how they differentiate between versions. Like between Pessach, Sukkoth and Shavuoth Machzorim, which use plenty common pages.

In the case of the Machzor Rabba, they really used the same text for both version - but switched some critical pages for Nussach Ashkenaz.

Since the Ashkenaz and Sefard machzorim are so similar, they put an א in the margin for the Ashkenaz-specific pages.

If you pay close attention you can find places in the Ashkenaz machzor that are clearly Nussach Sefard. Occasionally you'll find a "dual Nussach" like the  וְיַצְמַח פֻּרְקָנֵה, וִיקָרֵב מְשִׁיחֵהּ put in parentheses. This saves them from having to double-print too many pages.

So the Ashkenaz-specific pages are identified, to help the binding process. (In Israel, the printer and the binder are usually separate businesses.)

Comment: Interestingly enough, I cannot find a Google related answer to this phenomenon.

Comment: I actually suspected something like this.

Comment: Danny, I suspect that this is a more practical printer's note than that. Having done imposition (setting type for printing a book) I suspect that it's a simple note to line up printed pages in preparation for cutting and folding them.