# bli neder on pas yisroel

Tags: halacha, nedarim-shevuot, stringency-chumrah, aseres-yemei-teshuva, pat-yisrael

During aseres yemei tshuva the Shulchan Aruch writes that one should not eat pas akum(palter).

Does one have to say bli neder to take this chumrah on,or since it is a halacha no bli neder is necessary and once aseres yemei tshuvah is over one can drop this chumrah?

Comment: Yes (no source, but it's Pashut).

Comment: Yes that one has to say bli neder?

Comment: Yes, one must say Beli Neder.

Comment: That's very interesting you would think the achronim would mention that.

Comment: What's your Hava Amina to think that you wouldn't have to?

Comment: Since it is brought in halacha ,so it is known one will stop after the 10 days

Comment: No (no source, but it's Pashut).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bli Neder Loophole](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12231/bli-neder-loophole)

Comment: @Naftali, definitely not a duplicate, since this is about a specific practice's status, though answers to that question could potentially inform answers to this one.

Answer (score 3):

The Beis Yosef in O.C. 603 quotes a Tashbet"z quoting R' Shmuel of Burnburk that one shouldn't accept not to eat pas palter during aseres yemei teshuva because if he did he'd have to continue keeping it all year. We don't pasken like that which is where the Aruch HaShulchan is coming from. That being the case I think it's clear from the poskim the way they deal with the issue that there is no need to say "bli neder", because that's the issue R' Shmuel had with this custom.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for contributing your knowledge. Hope you stick around.

Answer (score 2):

*Aruch Hashulchan* (603) says:

> …so he wrote that even someone who is not careful all year with bread of a non-Jew should be careful during the ten days of return, q.v.
>
> It seems to me that that's true only of things that have no legal prohibition — like this, which is only a pretty thing to do (*hidur*), so it's appropriate to prettify thusly during these days. But things that some people have ruled are prohibited legally, but that people act on according to the lenient ones, such as *chadash* outside Israel, flesh without an adhesion, and the like — one cannot act thusly [=in accordance with those who rule stringently] during the ten days of return. After all, since [those who might do so] would be refraining from eating [such food] during these days, it'd be as if they accepted the prohibitors' view upon themselves, so how could they eat it afterward?

It seems that *Aruch Hashulchan* holds that the "it'd be as if they accepted the prohibitors' view upon themselves, so how could they eat it afterward?" argument does not apply to *pas palter*, bread of a non-Jew, and that he'd thus not require *hataras n'darim*, which would be specifically for something that, without such *hatara*, would remain prohibited.

---

If I might add my own thoughts — *hataras n'darim* requires that the person seeking the *hatara* have a *pesach*, some situation that has arisen that he did not anticipate when making his *neder*: had he anticipated it, he'd never have made the *neder*. If that were required here, then presumably "it's too hard to keep this rule all year" is insufficient a *pesach* year after year after year: at some point, he should anticipate it's not going to work. So he'd need some other *pesach*. Yet we find no mention in *halacha* of *hataras n'darim* or finding a *pesach* or specifying "*b'li neder*" about *pas palter* in the ten days of return. That alone seems strong evidence that it's not considered a *neder* affecting the time after *Yom Kipur*.